# 25th percentile for multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I have a table with columns `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`, etc. where each column is an `int`.  This table is populated with hundreds of rows with random values in each column.  What is the optimal way to return the value corresponding to the 25th percentile for each column?

For example:

```
A B C D E
1 5 8 9 3
3 6 5 0 2
8 3 6 1 8
4 1 8 3 1
7 2 2 6 9
```

Here column `A` is composed of the values 1, 3, 4, 8, and 7.  The 25th percentile for this set should be **3**.  Column `B` is composed of the values 1, 2, 3, 5, and 6.  25th percentile for this set should be **2**.  `C` is **5**, `D` is **1**, and `E` is **2**.  Since there are 5 rows, the 25th percentile is simply the second smallest value.  If there were 40 rows it would be the 10th smallest value.  How can I efficiently write a query that returns:

```
A B C D E
3 2 5 1 2
```

---

**What I've tried:**

```
WITH 
    ATable as (
        SELECT A, CAST(NTILE(100) OVER (ORDER BY A) as int) as Percentile
        FROM MyTable
    ),
    BTable as (
        SELECT B, CAST(NTILE(100) OVER (ORDER BY B) as int) as Percentile
        FROM MyTable
    ),
    ...
SELECT
    (SELECT TOP 1 A FROM ATable where Percentile = 25) as A,
    (SELECT TOP 1 B FROM BTable where Percentile = 25) as B,
    ...
```

I have about 40 of these columns and my experience with my dataset and NTILE is with that many columns, performance becomes a serious problem.   Does anyone have a better idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is correct. I don't see a whizzier solution.

You require a different row *per column* so you have to query each column separately. If you have 40 columns then it's 40 CTEs joined together. Simple.

Normally, you'd expect a whole row or group or rows or a subset of columns for the rows(s) that meet some criteria: not expect each column to be queried separately to get values unrelated to other values in the same row.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  It's nice to know when I should stop looking.  Will air this question out for a few days before accepting an answer, but yours will do if nothing better arrives.  On a side note, I admit this question is odd in the abstract.  In concrete terms, I'm trying to do this with NBA (basketball) player data.  So imagine each column is an individual stat like points, assists, blocks, etc.  I need to determine, in one fell swoop, all the stats at the 25th percentile.  These 25th percentile stats represent the stats for a "generic sub" in a fantasy basketball sim I'm working on.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the following article is still relevant for the current versions of MS SQL server, but you might check it out

[A Better NTILE](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dmauri/archive/2006/03/17/9339.aspx)

Comment: thanks for this.  I'll try it out and see if it works.  If the promised 40x improvement bears fruit, that'll be fantastic.

Comment: If it bears fruit keep us posted